# Fromatting Multiple User Form's TextBoxes

Tags: excel, vba

I am constructing a big program based on MS Excel's User Forms.
To make it nice I need to format several TextBoxes to display numbers with thousand separators.

For one TextBox I would use

```
  TextBox8 = Format(TextBox8, "#,##0")
```

But any idea what could work for 60+ boxes?

What doesnt work:

a) the Controls property

```
  For i = 12 To 32
    Controls("TextBox" & i) = Format(Controls("TextBox" & i), "#,##0")
  Next i
```

b) and the For Each as the TextBoxes are not valid elements.

```
  For Each TB in UserForm.TextBoxes`
```

ANY IDEA not to code the same in 60 lines?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on exactly what isn't working with a)? Are you getting any error? Because implicit default member calls aside, it's pretty much equivalent to the answer below, which should work.

Comment: Well in the User Form INITIALIZE section it doesnt give you any error but the work is not done either! The TextBoxes are not set to the "#,##0" format.

Comment: See, that's a rather important piece of information that belongs in the actual question.

Comment: right ... its with the Private / Public subs to do. where shall I run my or #Kostas K's code in order to change all TextBox format?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
For i = 12 To 32
    With Controls("TextBox" & i)
        .Value = Format(.Value, "#,##0")
    End With
Next i
```